# Angular.js canceling $http requests inside bind() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-http

According to this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1159

this should work, shouldn't it?

```
el.bind('keyup', function() {       
    var canceler = $q.defer();
    $http.post('/api', data, {timeout: canceler.promise}).success(success);
    canceler.resolve();
});
```

because it doesn't fire the request at all, no errors or anything, could it be because it's inside a bind function?

Comment: Yes, if you are running 1.1.5 or greater.  Otherwise, you the other work around listed in the link you provided.

Comment: I'm running 1.1.5 it still doesn't fire the request at all.

Comment: then i'd contact the creator (as you already did on that forum) or use the work around that is provided on that same forum post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it indeed was because it's inside the nonangular bind() event, putting `scope.$apply()` after http and before resolve will fix it

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1159#issuecomment-20368490

```
el.bind('keyup', function() {       
    var canceler = $q.defer();
    $http.post('/api', data, {timeout: canceler.promise}).success(success);
    scope.$apply();
    canceler.resolve();
});
```